# Splitting a String by the numbers in between

Tags: java, string, split, digit

I'm trying to split a String at the numbers.
For example if I have

> String x = 2A2B;

I want to be able to be able to split the String into parts and then print out "AABB" to the screen. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Ok that's possible. Show us what have you done so far?

Comment: Look at for loops, `Integer.parseInt` and `String#charAt`. That should guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Below code snippet may help you

```
    String str = "3A2B";
    // split the string on
    String st[] = str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(st));
    for (String s : st) {
        String intValue = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
        int i = Integer.parseInt(intValue);
        char c = s.charAt(s.length()-1);
        while (i > 0) {
            System.out.print(c);
            i--;
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a java.util.Scanner

```
Scanner.nextInt()
Scanner.next()
```

They will help you with your task.

Answer (score 0):

It can server your basic purpose:

```
String x = "2A2B";
int times = 0;
for(char ch:x.toCharArray()){
    if(Character.isDigit(ch)){
        times = times*10+(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(ch)));
    }else{
        do{
            System.out.print(ch);
            times--;
        }while(times > 0);
        times = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using scanners + delimiters for this.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\d");
```

Will read the string, splitting it by digits (\d), and next() should first give "A", then "B"

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\D");
```

Will read the string, splitting by anything that's *not* a digit, next() should return "2", then "2"

Something like this maybe? (assuming there's always one number followed by one letter)

```
String rawSequence = "2U2D1L1R1L1R1B1A";
string newSequence = "";

Scanner scanLetters = new Scanner(rawSequence);
scanLetters.useDelimiter("\d");
Scanner scanNumbers = new Scanner(rawSequence);
scanLetter.useDelimeter("\D");

String[] letters = new String[ rawSequence.length()/2 ];
int[] amounts = new int[ rawSequence.length()/2 ];

for (int x = 0; x < rawSequence.length(); x++){
    letters[x] = scanLetters.next()
    numbers[x] = scanNumbers.next()
}

for (int i = 0, i < amounts.length, i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < amounts[i], j++){
        newSequence.concat(letters[i]);
    }
}
```